force terraform random_integer to generate new value
I have a terarform resource
resource "random_integer" "cluster" {
  min  = 300
  max  = 400
  seed = var.service_name
}

and it generated the same value for 2 different services in different state files. Is there a way to force this resource to generate new value for one of the services without changing the code?
Tried removing this resource from terraform state but it generated the same number.
I don't want it to create new value with each deploy, the question is how to force it to create a new value one time and then keep it. Or what to do in case of collision.

Well, it does say it will produce the same value: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/integer#seed. :)

If you simply left the seed attribute out, it would create a different value. You are forcing it to create the same value every time by setting the seed attribute.

I don't want it to create new value with each deploy, the question is how to force it to create a new value one time and then keep it.

"it generated the same value for 2 different services" this implies var.service_name is not resolving as expected, and so I would begin investigating around that issue.

Or random_integer doesn't guarantee a unique value?
